# Cannot display received data with txtStatus.Text but able to with txtStatus.AppendText

Tags: c#, tcp, textbox, server

I am doing a TCP server & client communication. I would like to display the received data (from client) on the textbox of the server.

When i used txtStatus.AppendText, it works perfectly fine. But when i changed to txtStatus.Text, nothing was shown in the textbox.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is my code for my server:

```
private void btnListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress ipaddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 123, 123, 123, 123 });
        //IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse(txtIP1.Text + "." + txtIP2.Text + "." + txtIP3.Text + "." + txtIP4.Text);
        //int portNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text);
        int portNum = 8500;
        TCPServerHelper.AcceptConnection(ipaddress, portNum);
        txtStatus.Text = "Connected to remote client!";

        while (true)
        {
                byte[] bufferReceivedData = TCPServerHelper.Read();
                MovementData recMovementData = (MovementData)TCPServerHelper.Deserialize(bufferReceivedData);

                try
                {
                    //txtStatus.AppendText(recMovementData.BaseMoveData.BaseMov.ToString());
                    txtStatus.Text = recMovementData.BaseMoveData.BaseMov.ToString();

                    DataHandler(recMovementData.BaseMoveData.BaseMov.ToString());
                }

                catch
                { }

            }
    }

    delegate void DataHandlerDelegate(string Direction);
    public void DataHandler(string Direction)
    {
        if (!this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            switch(Direction)
            {
                case "stop":
                    txtResult.Text = "stop";
                    break;

                case "forward":
                    txtResult.Text = "forward";
                    break;

                case "backward":
                    txtResult.Text = "backward";
                    break;

                case "left":
                    txtResult.Text = "left";
                    break;

                case "right":
                    txtResult.Text = "right";
                    break;

                case "clockwise":
                    txtResult.Text = "clockwise";
                    break;

                case "anti-clockwise":
                    txtResult.Text = "anti-clockwise";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BeginInvoke(new DataHandlerDelegate(DataHandler), new object[] { Direction });
        }
    }
```

Comment: TCP can return empty packets of data and packets can contain up to ~1500 bytes.  You are getting multiple packets (going through while loop more than once) and the last loop doesn't have any data.  So append is displaying all the data while not using append is only displaying only the last read.  I would ignore and read data where the byte count is zero.

Comment: Thanks alot! Finally i see a clearer picture now @jdweng